# issue with pointers and constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

The following code doesn't work:

```
class String{
public:
    char* str;
    int* counter;

    String(){
        str = NULL;
        counter = new int;
        *counter = 1;
    };
    String(const char* str1){
        String();
        str = new char[strlen(str1)+1];
        strcpy(str, str1);
    };


 };
```

I've changed the call to the empty constructor and replaced it with its internals, and now the following code works:

```
class String{
public:
    char* str;
    int* counter;

    String(){
        str = NULL;
        counter = new int;
        *counter = 1;
    };
    String(const char* str1){
        //String();
        str = new char[strlen(str1)+1];
        strcpy(str, str1);
        counter = new int;
        *counter = 1;
    };
```

Can you please suggest why?

Thanks, Li.

Comment: You should state what is it that you consider did not work, what is it that you believe to work now and probably give a rational on what you are trying to achieve. For starters, you should use `std::string` as it already works, from there on... both of the implementations that you provided leak memory, the counter need not be dynamically allocated, it is usually a bad idea to have your members exposed...

Comment: why do you want to call the default constructor, seems it doesn't have added value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Doesn't work" is not a good description of the problem. But you apparently tried to invoke a constructor from another one. That's called constructor delegation and is not (yet) supported by C++.

BTW, a class like this should get a user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor.

Answer (score 2):

In the current C++, constructors cannot call each other. That's called "chaining constructors", or "delegating constructors" and is supported by the new C++0x standard but with a different syntax than the one you are using.

Off-topic, why do you use a pointer to int for the counter?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you are trying to invoke a constructor from another constructor of the same class, like you would in C# for example. Unfortunately you cannot do this in C++ (at least no easy way I know of). You need to either have a private method or duplicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

Calling String(); actually creates a temporary object and then throws it away again.  It won't call the other constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The call `'String();'` creates an unnamed temporary object of type `String` that is destroyed immediately. The second code snippet is fine.

However you should really relook at the members of your class. Use std::string instead of raw char pointer. Also `int *counter` does not look very intuitive

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to do something like this:

```
class String{

public:
    char* str;
    int* counter;

private:
    void initialize() {
        str = NULL;
        counter = new int;
        *counter = 1;
    }
public: 
    String(){
        initialize();
    };
    String(const char* str1){
        initialize();
        str = new char[strlen(str1)+1];
        strcpy(str, str1);
    };


 };
```

Answer (score 0):

- why is the counter a pointer ?

What does not work ? compilation error ?

Probably calling the constructor inside another is not well supported on your compiler ?

what platform ?